# Create a restriction on number of related rows (foreign key) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, implementation

For example, I want to create 1:1 mandatory on one side between two entities.
For that I create foreign key and copy PK to new attribute in child entity. So I get something like this:
[Relation between two entities picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPUFm.png)
But if I want to create that in SQL Server, it will look like it is normal 1:* relationship. So to make it be real 1:1 relationship I need to create UNIQUE constraint on foreign key attribute, am I right?

Another question, if I have 1:* relationship and I want it to be restricted like [1..100], is it possible in SQl Server? For example, DB for Car Seller stations all over the city, it has Employees, each of them is responsible for some cars. One employee can't be responsible for more than 50 cars, because he just can't pay needed attention to all of them at once.

Comment: relation ship 1:* is called one to many,its not a constraint

Comment: Yes, I know that. I mean, how can I create 1:* relationship that has a restriction [1..100]? Is it possible with some constraint?

Comment: if I have relationship with restriction 1..100, what constraint it is?,i focused on this part

Comment: SQL dont have such constraint,would you share on the need of such

Comment: As mentioned in one answer,you can enforce 1:1 using unique constraint as foreign key and certainly 1:100 can be done through custom programming,but it would good to know what is the reason for adopting this

Comment: Thank you very much, now I got it.
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a unique constraint on a foreign key.  This is a common technique to make a 1:1 relationship.

It is not quite a 1:1 relationship since one side may exist and the other may not and since SQL Server does not support deferred foreign key constraints you can't enforce reciprocity.

So a unique constraint on the foreign key is as close as you can come to a 1:1 relationship with SQL Server.

For a 1:(0-100) constraint, I would add a second piece to the unique key which is an integer between 1 and 100 and require that this not be null.  That poses some problems but it does solve the problem at hand.